# WPF Command with multiple target types

Tags: wpf, command

I'm a bit confused about WPF commands with different target types.

So if I define a command

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        Executed="CopyCmdExecuted"
                        CanExecute="CopyCmdCanExecute"/>

    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

And now I use it in a context menu:

```
                    <ContextMenu Name="FolderContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem Command="Copy"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
```

And I have a method to handle the command:

```
private void CopyCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{


}
```

And I use it in a plain old menu:

```
    <Menu  Name="editMenu">
        <MenuItem Command="Copy"/>
    </Menu>
```

I have no problem understanding that. But I'm a bit confused what I am supposed to do if the target objects are different types.

Lets say I have Folders and Users, both of which have a context menu with the New command (and the menu bar edit menu which also has the New command).

When New is executed, regardless of whether its a Folder or a User, CopyCmdExecuted is executed. So, am I now supposed to de-multiplex on the target? Something like

```
   private void CopyCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           if(sender is User)
               // Do copy user stuff
           if(sender is Folder)
               // Do copy folder stuff
        }
```

If I end up with lots of data types I wish to copy, it seems a bit annoying. Am I not understanding something here?

(Obviously, I could just have Folder and User inherit from a Copiable base class with DoCopy but that still seems wrong.)

Comment: @user570577: That's pretty much how I've been doing it anyway.. Thought the same thing at first

Comment: +1 Haven't done much with routed commands, just [RelayCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030). Good question!

Answer (score 2):

You can send a `CommandParameter` when you invoke the `Command` to indicate what you mean the command to apply to.  Here's are two `TextBlock` elements:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="File">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem
                        Command="Copy"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock2" Text="Folder">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem
                        Command="Copy"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and this code-behind:

```
    private void CopyCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = (e.Parameter as TextBlock).Text;
        Debug.WriteLine("Text = " + text);
    }
```

uses the parameter to figure out which `TextBlock` the context menu applies to.  You can also just use the strings `"File"` and `"Folder"` if that works for you.

Comment: That is a great solution for ContextMenu's. But it won't work for the single Edit menu for the entire application. Because there is only one menu you can't set different CommandParameter's.

Comment: In that case you can use `Keyboard.FocusedElement'`.  The advantage of a `CommandParameter` if you can use it is that it works for element that cannot receive the focus.